# virtualenv does not get activated in new bash shell

Tags: linux, python-2.7, terminal, virtualenv

I activate python virtualenv in one bash and tries to use in another bash shell. virtualenv simply does not work.

I opened a terminal, activate the virtualenv through sourcing activate file. It got activated in my terminal it shows () in front of terminal address.

I opened a new terminal. The effect is not visible in the newly opened terminal.

Anyone here help me please?

Comment: Sourcing files executes every command in the respective file in the current shell. As a result, you modify the environment of this (and only this) shell. If you want the sourcing to be persistent and for all future shells, you can put the source command into ~/.bashrc or into ~/.bash_profile  (... in fact, ~/.bashrc is - usually, in most bash configurations - sourced from ~/.bash_profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to activate the virtualenv in every shell, or, as 0range suggested, activate it in your .bashrc or any script running before your shell displays the prompt.

To add it to your .bashrc :

- Edit /home/youruser/.bashrc and add the line : `source /path/to/bin/activate`
- Open a new shell or `source ~/.bashrc`

Everything should be alright.